# Replacing a parameter in a text file based on the latest filename in a directory

Tags: bash

I have the following text file (namelist.txt)

```
&share
  wrf_core = 'ARW',
  max_dom = 3,
  start_date ='YYYY-MM-DD_HH:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD_HH:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD_HH:00:00',
  end_date   ='YYYY-MM-DD_HH:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD_HH:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD_HH:00:00',
  interval_seconds = 21600,
  io_form_geogrid = 2,
  debug_level=0,
/
```

I want to replace the YYYY, MM, DD, and HH based on the *latest* filename of a directory.
For example:

An INPUT folder contains the following subdirectories:

```
2021021000
2021021006
2021021012
2021021018
2021021100
```

The latest directory from the above is **2021021100**

I'm stuck here. The script should read the latest filename of the sub-directory inside the INPUT folder and do the following.

```
year=$(echo $line | cut -c1-4)
echo $year
month=$(echo $line | cut -c5-6)
echo $month
day=$(echo $line | cut -c7-8)
echo $day
hour=$echo $line | cut -c9-10)
echo $hour

sed -i 's/'YYYY'/'$year'/g' namelist.txt
sed -i 's/'MM'/'$month'/g' namelist.txt
sed -i 's/'DD'/'$day'/g' namelist.txt
sed -i 's/'HH'/'$hour'/g' namelist.txt
```

The desired output should be like this:

```
 &share
  wrf_core = 'ARW',
  max_dom = 3,
  start_date ='2021-02-11_00:00:00','2021-02-11_00:00:00','2021-02-11_00:00:00',
  end_date   ='2021-02-11_00:00:00','2021-02-11_00:00:00','2021-02-11_00:00:00',
  interval_seconds = 21600,
  io_form_geogrid = 2,
  debug_level=0,
/
```

How can I do this in bash?

I'll appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Get the directory with the latest date

Bash's globs (`*` and so on) expand in a sorted order. If the subdirectories in your current working directory are only named in the style `YYYYMMDDHH` then `*/` will expand to a list of dates where the last date is at the end of the list. To retrieve only the last entry from that list you can use either an array, a function (using `shift`), or a command (for instance `printf | tail`). Here we go with the array:

```
#! /bin/bash
cd INPUT
dirs=(*/)
last="${dirs[-1]}"
cd -
```

If there are also other directories you can change the glob so that only directories of the format `YYYYMMDDHH` are accepted:

```
dirs=([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9][0-2][0-9]/)
```

#### Replacing the placeholders

You don't need four `cut` and four `sed`. The following should work as well:

```
sed -i "s/YYYY-MM-DD_HH/${last:0:4}-${last:4:2}-${last:6:2}_${last:8:2}/g" yourFile
```

Comment: @socowi..I have a question regarding the "sed" command. How can I change the "sed" command such that everytime a new directory appears inside the INPUT, the YYYY-MM-DD_HH will change?

Comment: @Lyndz `sed` alone won't cut it in this case. You have to put a loop around `sed` that watches the INPUT directory and calls `sed` every time the last date changes. Have a look at `inotifywait`. If you get stuck, please open a new question.

Comment: I posted the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66243598/how-to-implement-a-waiting-function-in-bash

Answer (score 1):

GNU Awk is a possibility for this:

```
awk -v dat="2021021100" 'BEGIN { yr=substr(dat,1,4);mn=substr(dat,5,2);day=substr(dat,7,2);hr=substr(dat,9,2)} /YYYY-MM-DD_HH/ { gsub("YYYY-MM-DD_HH",yr"-"mn"-"day"_"hr,$0) }1' namelist.txt > namelist.tmp && mv -f namedlist.tmp namedlist.txt
```

Explanation:

```
awk -v dat="2021021100"                                    # Pass the date as a variable dat to awk
      'BEGIN { 
               yr=substr(dat,1,4);                         # Before processing the file, use substr to extract the time elements from dat
               mn=substr(dat,5,2);
               day=substr(dat,7,2);
               hr=substr(dat,9,2)} 
       /YYYY-MM-DD_HH/ { 
               gsub("YYYY-MM-DD_HH",yr"-"mn"-"day"_"hr,$0) # When we find YYYY-MM-DD_HH" in the line, use gsub to substitute this for the yr,mn,day and hr.
              }1' namedfile                                # Print all lines amended or otherwise
```

If you have more recent versions of GNU awk, can use the -i flag for "in file" changes as opposed to using a tmp file and actioning mv.

Comment: I think you missed the actual question. OP didn't ask about doing the replacement, but about retrieving the latest date from a list of directory names. Quote: *`The script should read the latest filename of the subsdirectory inside the INPUT folder`*