# How to implement a waiting function in BASH whenever a new directory appears

Tags: bash, wait

I have the following text file (namelist.txt)

```
&share
  wrf_core = 'ARW',
  max_dom = 3,
  start_date ='YYYY-MM-DD_HH:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD_HH:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD_HH:00:00',
  end_date   ='YYYY-MM-DD_HH:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD_HH:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD_HH:00:00',
  interval_seconds = 21600,
  io_form_geogrid = 2,
  debug_level=0,
/
```

An INPUT folder contains the following subdirectories:

```
2021021000
2021021006
2021021012
2021021018
2021021100
```

I want to update the YYYY-MM-DD_HH everytime a new subdirectory appears in the INPUT folder.

I have the following script so far.

```
#! /bin/bash
cd INPUT
dirs=([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9][0-2][0-9]/)
last="${dirs[-1]}"

sed -i "s/YYYY-MM-DD_HH/${last:0:4}-${last:4:2}-${last:6:2}_${last:8:2}/g" namelist.txt
```

After some other process, I type this to go back to the original YYYY-MM-DD_HH:

```
sed -i "s/${last:0:4}-${last:4:2}-${last:6:2}_${last:8:2}/YYYY-MM-DD_HH/g" namelist.txt
```

(a) Is there a more efficient way to do this in bash?

(b) Is there a "wait" function in bash so that the process will not proceed if there is no new directory available?

How can I implement this such that the script would only run again after this **2021021106** directory appears.

I'll appreciate any help on this.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/181517/how-to-execute-a-command-whenever-a-file-changes

Comment: hmm..im not sure @AvenDesta the file is not changing but another directory is appearing in my case

Comment: Looks like you are looking for `inotifywait`. It requires kernel support but should be trivial on modern platforms.